# Is there a book which can help with Quranic Arabic?

Tags: quran, arabic, books

Do you have a recommendation for a book that makes, shall I say, a "Gateway" to Quranic Arabic? Something that will help me understand the Arabic of the Quran better if I will read it before reading the Quran itself.

Comment: Do you know standard Arabic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for a [book recommendation](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/261/17163).